# How to boot from a bootable ubuntu external hard drive on Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, boot, external-hard-drive

I have my pc hard drive which I turned into portable using hard drive cases provided in market. I then installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onto that hard drive. I know how to boot from that hard drive on a normal pc i.e. using boot menu we can change the order of booting from the external hard drive. However, I don't know the process in Mac. Can someone point me in right Direction. If I could boot from External Hard Drive having Ubuntu or not? If I need rEFInd for that I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: [How to, finally, get Ubuntu to boot on a mac from external USB storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525845/how-to-finally-get-ubuntu-to-boot-on-a-mac-from-external-usb-storage):

- Boot with bootable USB, install Ubuntu
- Partition your USB as follows:

  - 200MB EFI boot partition
  - 200MB ext2, mount to /boot
  - Swap space if you want it
  - One or more other partitions to hold Ubuntu proper (e.g. ext4 on /)
- Complete the install, reboot to OS X
- Get gdisk (pkg installer for OS X) and rEFInd binaries
- execute "diskutil list" from the console and note the device name, and the EFI partition (e.g. /dev/disk3, /dev/disk3s1)
- Follow the gdisk recipe at http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/ under "Fixing the installation" point 6
- Install rEFInd on your USB's EFI partition. From the refind directory: ./install.sh -–usedefault /dev/disk3s1

Then when you reboot, you can "EFI Boot" to rEFInd, and there should be an option to boot GRUB/linux.